# c# using program.cs to refer to form2 in form1 has error

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static Form1 f;
        public static Form2 f2;
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
            f = new Form1();
            f2 = new Form2();
        }
    }
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Program.f2.Show();
```

this.Hide();
    }

The button gives "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. How do I fix this? I don't see any error in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Means that the object u are trying to call, has not been initialized yet, you are calling `f2.Show();`, but you have to initialize it before calling it.

You should initialize Form2 and then call it using the name you gave it.

Replace:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Program.f2.Show();
   this.Hide(); 
}
```

With:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var f2 = new Form2();
     f2.Show();
     this.Hide();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem technically lies here:

```
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        f = new Form1();
        f2 = new Form2();
```

Application.Run() actually blocks until the main form is closed, therefore the two lines below (where you initialize the forms) never gets run.  To "fix" it, you'd need to move those lines up:

```
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        f = new Form1();
        f2 = new Form2();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
```

It looks like you wanted "f" to be a reference to Form1, though, so you should pass that to Application.Run() instead:

```
        f = new Form1();
        f2 = new Form2();
        Application.Run(f);
```

I would wrap those instances in a property, however, so you can make sure they are instantiated correctly (such as when you close Form2 and try to re-open it again).  That could look something like this:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    private static Form1 f1;
    private static Form2 f2;

    public static Form1 F1
    {
        get
        {
            if (f1 == null || f1.IsDisposed)
            {
                f1 = new Form1();
            }
            return f1;
        }
    }

    public static Form2 F2
    {
        get
        {
            if (f2 == null || f2.IsDisposed)
            {
                f2 = new Form2();
            }
            return f2;
        }
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(Program.F1);
    }

}
```

Then over in Form1:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program.F2.Show();
    }
```